# Replace two consecutive CR with one

Tags: command-line, text-processing

`cat -e file.txt` gives:

```
{"yellow":"mango"}^M$
^M$
{"yellow":"banana"}^M$
^M$
{"yellow":"blabla"}^M$
^M$
```

and I would like to just have:

```
{""yellow":"mango"}^M$
{"yellow":"banana"}^M$
{"yellow":"blabla"}^M$
```

in place for all files with txt extention in folder. So I tried:

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i "s/^M$^M$/^M$/g"
```

to no avail. Does anyone have a better idea?

```
head -n 3 file.txt | od -bc
```

yields:

```
0000000 173 042 171 145 154 154 157 167 042 072 042 155 141 156 147 157
          {   "   y   e   l   l   o   w   "   :   "   m   a   n   g   o
0000020 042 175 015 012 015 012 173 042 142 141 142 141 142 042 072 042
          "   }  \r  \n  \r  \n   {   "   b   a   b   a   b   "   :   "
0000040 155 141 156 147 157 042 175 015 012
          m   a   n   g   o   "   }  \r  \n
0000051
```

this:

```
awk 1 RS='\r\n' ORS= < file.txt
```

removes the new lines completely (so it's not good: I want to keep one of the successive two on each line, but it does something).

Comment: The `$` from `cat -e` is an end-of-line indicator, and is not in the file. Inspect the file with `head -n 3 fille.txt | od -bc` and use `xargs -0 sed -i "s/^M^M/^M/g`.

Comment: added the result of inspect. strangely s/^M^M/^M/g doesn't help. Nor does sed -e 's/\\r\\n\\r\\n/\\r\\n/g' file.txt

Comment: Does `sed -e 's/\r\n\r\n/\r\n/g' file.txt` work?

Comment: @MaxSilvester: no

Comment: When asking a question, state the goal, not the means you try to (maybe) achieve it : Do you really want to "replace to consecutive crlf with one" (and thus, if you ever have 4 consecutive crlf you end up with 2 consecutive crlf in the endfile, and thus have at least 1 empty line) ? or do you want to get rid of all empty lines instead?

Comment: @OlivierDulac: I dunno. For many years, the first comment below one of my questions with no trial code was "what have you tried to solve the problem?"

Comment: @user2413 it is good practice to do both : 1) state the goal (I need to do this to the data, in order to get this information/result) and 2) show what you tried to do so. If you only state what you tried (as here, you seem to really try to have every "2 consecutive \r\n" become "1 \r\n") it may sometimes be not the proper thing to attempt in order to achieve the goal (if, for exemple, the goal is to get rid of all empty lines). I shouldn't have said "not the means you try ..." but "**before** showing the means you try ...", my bad

Comment: note: if the goal was to get rid of empty lines: You could `find . -type f -name "*.txt" -print0 | xargs -0 grep -h -E -v "^$(printf '\015')$|^$"`  for exemple. (-h to not display the prefix "filename:" if there are more than 1 txt file given to grep)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `sed -z 's/\r\n\r\n/\r\n/g'`.

Normally `sed` only works on one line at a time. By using the `-z` option, `sed` will work on lines, which are seperated by `0` bytes, which normally don't exist in a text file, so the whole file will be treated as one line and newlines can be replaced.

(found on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30049447/11485791) and added explanation)

Comment: You solution works. I had accidentally changed the file ending with one of my trials! But going back to the original file, it's this!

Comment: Don't try this on a multi-GB file.

Comment: Although this is for Ubuntu, warning to those that aren't using Ubuntu: This only works on GNU/sed, i.e. not Alpine, an initial ramdisk environment or similar.

Comment: @GuntramBlohmsupportsMonica `sed -I` on a large file is very slow no matter what operation you try to perform; but without `-I`, it should be reasonably fast.

Answer (score 12):

You can also delete lines that contain only the carriage return.

- With GNU Sed:

  ```
  sed '/^\r$/d' file
  ```
- For a minimal but POSIX compliant machine (here we need to generate the carriage return with Printf):

  ```
  sed "/^$(printf "\r")$/d" file
  ```

`^` matches the start-of-line and the last `$`, the end-of-line (`\n`).

For example:

```
$ cat -e file
AB^M$
^M$
CB^M$
^M$
$ sed '/^\r$/d' file|cat -e
AB^M$
CB^M$
```

Comment: This is probably the better answer, depending on the actual requirements

Answer (score 2):

If it's okay to remove all blank lines, you can do:

```
perl -wlne '/\S/ and print' old_file > new_file
```

And if you prefer to overwrite your file(s), you can use the `-i` (in-place) switch:

```
perl -wlni.bak -e '/\S/ and print' file1 file2 file3 ...
```

The above line will copy the original files as `*.bak` files.  If you don't care about having backups, then you can just leave out the `.bak` part, like this:

```
perl -wlni -e '/\S/ and print' file1 file2 file3 ...
```

(You can even use wildcards, so instead of `file1 file2 file3 ...` you can write `file*` .)

The advantage of this approach is that it makes changes to your files all at once (instead of having to run it once for each file).

But remember:  This will only keep lines that contain at least one non-whitespace character.  So if a line consists only of five spaces, a tab, a carriage return, and a line-feed character, it won't be kept.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could use awk's Record Separator and Output Record Separator to achieve the goal, which should be more efficient on very large files than `sed -z ...`.

```
awk '
  BEGIN {
    RS = "\r\n\r\n"
    ORS = "\r\n"
  }

  {
    print $0
  }

' inputFile > outputFile
```

Comment: This is nice +1. It is also equivalent to `awk 1 RS="\r\n\r\n" ORS="\r\n"`. Just bear in mind it adds a final blank line if the file does not terminate with a blank line and that a multi-character record separator is unespecified by [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html). For example, GNU awk will give wrong results if given the `--posix` flag.

Answer (score 1):

**Using Raku (the language formerly known as Perl6)**

```
~$ raku -ne '.put if /\S/ ;' test_blank.txt
{"yellow":"mango"}
{"yellow":"banana"}
{"yellow":"blabla"}
```

The example above only prints lines that contain non-whitespace characters (`\S` matches a single character that is not whitespace). A very readable version below:

```
~$ raku -ne '.put if .chars;' test_blank.txt
{"yellow":"mango"}
{"yellow":"banana"}
{"yellow":"blabla"}
```

HTH.

https://raku.org
https://rakudo.org/downloads